# How to have Centering the number with formatting already in the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I really like to use some of the preset format for numbers in excel. I was trying this to use the Accounting format then changing the format without the prefix symbol ($). After making these changes I was not able to center the column of numbers. I did read some suggestions here [About centering the number](https://superuser.com/questions/743499/excel-formatting-not-working-for-some-cells-when-trying-to-do-center-alignment). The answers recommended basically to remove preexisting formats. I want to keep the format that I have chosen so these solutions don't work. I also tried to go into the custom format and change the **Type:** text **_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);*(* "-"??*);*(@*)**. I tried removing underscores.

None of these worked for me. Do you know how to get centering working with preexisting formatting?

Comment: quick google found this:https://www.auditexcel.co.za/blog/excel-refuses-to-align-a-number-left-or-centre/#:~:text=As%20shown%20below%2C%20highlight%20the%20cells%20where%20the,the%20%2A%20in%20the%20format%2C%205%20Click%20OK.

Comment: @gns100 The link to the blog did not work.

Comment: The link works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the solution**

1. go to Format Cells,
2. Click on Custom,
3. You will see the code that tells Excel to use the Accounting Format, *(* #,##0.00*);*(* (#,##0.00);*(* "0"??*);*(@_)
4. Delete the * in the format,
5. Click OK.

The result should look like this.
*( #,##0.00*);*( (#,##0.00);*( "0"??*);*(@_)